# Get a variable from one wordpress template file to another

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I have a template file (**trendingPosts.php**) for showing 2 latest posts with the tag 'trending'. In the while loop for displaying these 2 posts, I take their ID's in an array so I can exclude them from the main wordpress loop later:

```
<div id="trendingWrap" class="clearfix">

<?php
$trending = new WP_Query();
$trending->query("showposts=2&tag=trending");
while($trending->have_posts()) : $trending->the_post();
$wp_query->in_the_loop = true;
$currentTrending[] = $post->ID;
?>

    <div class="trendingStory">
        <h2 class="trendingTitle"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    </div><!-- end trendingStory -->

<?php endwhile; ?>

</div><!-- end trendingWrap -->
```

The problem is that I have an **index.php** in which I include the **loop.php** via `get_template_part( 'loop', 'index' );` and I am unable to get the `$currentTrending[]` array that I made in **trendingPosts.php**. **I need to get that array in my *loop.php***

Moreover, in my **loop.php**, I am excluding the 2 posts in the following way.

```
if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    if( $post->ID == $currentTrending[0] || $post->ID == $currentTrending[1] ) continue;
```

Is this the right way to exclude posts? if anybody has a better way of doing this whole thing. Please let me know. **Of course nothing works until I manage to get that array in *loop.php* so that is the main issue.**

Thanks! I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response, but the method below works for me with almost no change in my code.

Comment: You should put that comment beneath the other answer ;) And a vote up is always a nice form of saying thanks (little hint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily create variables that you can access everywhere by using the [`$GLOBALS`](http://php.net/reserved.variables.globals) [superglobal](http://php.net/language.variables.superglobals) array.

Once set

```
$GLOBALS['mytheme_thisismyvar'] = 22;
```

You can then access it everwhere in the other templates:

```
$myvar = $GLOBALS['mytheme_thisismyvar'];
```

And use it where it suits. This works with sub-templates regardless how they get loaded.

Because the whole program shares this superglobal array, take care that you do not overwrite existing values.

Comment: Awesome! That worked...best part: I didn't have to change my code.

Answer (score 2):

Try moving your current trending code to the theme's functions.php, so that you can call on it whenever you need.

```
function getCurrentTrending() {
  $trending = new WP_Query();
  $trending->query("showposts=2&tag=trending");
  while($trending->have_posts()) : $trending->the_post();
    $wp_query->in_the_loop = true;
    $currentTrending[] = $post->ID;
  endwhile;
  return $currentTrending;
}
```

You can then fetch that array from any template file:

```
$currentTrending = getCurrentTrending();
```

Hope that helps.