# Can't get globals variable to work, how to pass the value from template to function in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress

Edited:
Problem is that when doing ajax loading of more posts the $year1 or $year value gets repeated. The value of $year is actually a month.

How it looks now:

- December
- Event 1
- November
- Event 2
- Event 3
- November--- here the ajax call happens and the month value gets repeated
- Event 4
- Event 5
- Event 6

and How it should be:

- December
- Event 1
- November
- Event 2
- Event 3
- Event 4
- Event 5
- Event 6

I have so far tried with globals variables
[Get a variable from one wordpress template file to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6322304/get-a-variable-from-one-wordpress-template-file-to-another)
and get query variables
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96312/get-query-var-vs-global-query-variables

Another problem is that the date in functions.php returns the values in english, while the same code returns the date in spanish
in the template.

Code in template: Do note I used the $test variable with November value for testing porpuses, but it should be $year1
I don't know what I am doing wrong...

```
$my_posts = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : 
        ?>

          <div class="my-posts2">



            <?php while ( $my_posts->have_posts() ) : $my_posts->the_post() ?>

              <?php 

             $dateformatstring = 'F';
             $unixtimestamp = strtotime(get_field('start_date'));
             $year1 = date_i18n($dateformatstring, $unixtimestamp);
             $year_check2 = $GLOBALS['year_checkbarcelonafunctions'];

             // If your year hasn't been echoed earlier in the loop, echo it now
             if (($year1 !== $year_check1) && ($year1 !== $year_check2)){
                 echo "<h2 class='year-act text-center'>" . $year1 . "</h2>";
                 }

             // Now that your year has been printed, assign it to the $year_check variable
                $test = 'November';
                $GLOBALS['year_checkbarcelona1'] = $test;

                $year_check1 = $year1;



                ?>
```

Code in functions.php:

```
function load_posts_by_ajax_callback2() {
    check_ajax_referer('load_more_posts2', 'security2');
    $paged = $_POST['page'];
    $today = current_time('Y-m-d');
        $args = array (
              'meta_query'             => array(
                'relation'    => 'AND',
                array(
                  'category'         => 'actividades',
                    'key'       => 'start_date',
                    'value'     => $today,
                    'compare'   => '<',
                    'type'      => 'DATE',
                    ),
                array(
                    'key'   => 'region',
                    'value'   => 'Barcelona',
                    'compare' => '='
                    ),


            ),
            'meta_key'               => 'start_date',
            'orderby'                => 'meta_value',
            'order'                  => 'DSC',
            'posts_per_page' => 3, 
            'paged' => $paged,


        );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
        <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();?>
                <?php 

             $dateformatstring = 'F';
             $unixtimestamp = strtotime(get_field('start_date'));
             $year = date_i18n($dateformatstring, $unixtimestamp);

           //Example another global
           //$paged = $_POST['page'];
             $year_check1 = $GLOBALS['year_checkbarcelona1'];        


             // If your year hasn't been echoed earlier in the loop, echo it now
             if (($year !== $year_check) && ($year !== $year_check1)){

                 echo "<h2 class='year-act text-center'>" . $year . "</h2>";        
                 }          


             // Now that your year has been printed, assign it to the $year_check variable
             $GLOBALS['year_checkbarcelonafunctions'] = $year;
             $year_check = $year;

             ?>
```

So in other words, the global values should avoid duplicating the $year tag that groups the activities/events when doing ajax loading.

Edit: I'm open to other solutions that don't rely on globals.

Edit3: I'm using this code (that is not working) inside the loop of the events template:

```
global $mytest2;
$mytest2 = 'November';
```

and in the functions.php inside the function load_posts_by_ajax_callback2, I have tried with

```
             ob_start();
             global $mytest2;
             echo $mytest2;
             $myStr = ob_get_contents();
             ob_end_clean();                     


             if (($year !== $year_check) && ($year !== $myStr)){

                 echo "<h2 class='year-act text-center'>" . $year . "</h2>";        
                 }
```

Comment: Global values should always be avoided.

Comment: I'm open to better solutions..

Comment: Other than the English/Spanish problem, you haven't stated: what the problem is, what is occurring, what you have tried, what error messages you may or may not be getting, what the value is supposed to be vs. what it is, and you haven't actually asked a question. Start with those things and you'll be much more likely to get help; make it as easy as possible for someone who has never seen your code to understand what the problem is/what's going on.

Comment: Thank you KayakinKoder!! You are completely right I have edited/updated the question.